# XmlPullParser.nextTag throwing an exception

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following code :

```
InputStream is = assetManager.open(Constants.ATTRIBUTE_XML_URL);
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(is));
parser.nextTag();
```

InputStream 'is' is getting populated with the xml. But it throws a null pointer when it reaches the `ёparser.nextTag()`;

What mistake am I making? Or is there a better way to parse an XML in android?

Comment: Please show the exception

Answer (score 0):

This method will call `next()` and return `event` if it is `START_TAG` or `END_TAG` otherwise throw an exception. Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) you need to read so you understand how to parse xml.